# Double byte encoding issue in UI

Tags: java, encoding, utf

There is a weird behavior i am seeing in my application UI

The same set of characters are getting displayed correctly in UI in one place and same set is displayed wrongly in another place

江苏南通二建集团有限公司  -----------------> The correct display

江苏南通二���集团有限公司 ---------------------> The wrong display

We are using utf-8 every where

Comment: Can you also show us the relevant code around these encoding conversions?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Is it the same UI-Element-Class (Label, TextBox, whatever) whith same Font?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? A simple `Label` which shows the text properly on one machine but not on the other would be sufficient. Also, which Java version are you using on each of the machines? Is it the absolutely same?

Comment: I am using java 6 in app the gives the response . The UI is mounted on a different app server running on java 7 . The architecture is we have a service app server which produces a json(Built using JAXRS ) and UI uses jquery to consume and render stuff .It resides in a seperate app server . What is see in browser console is the service giving junk value in one part of the json and the same value comes correctly in another part of the json

Comment: If I get it right, running on **Java 6** is giving the **wrong** output, right?

Comment: I think yes . But my doubt is if its wrong in one place , It should appear wrong everywhere in the response .. Why only one place in the response . Any idea .  The snippet of the code that thows out the response ======return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(finalResponse).build();

Answer (score 1):

Find some points where you could start with your investigation. As on your side different applications/environments involved it's quite difficult from outside to give a solution.

For me it looks not like a general encoding problem, because only one single character gets garbled. The normal behavior in case of encoding problems is that the broken character is replaced by the [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character) �. In your case there are three of them. Therefore I believe there is somewhere in the processing some code which analyses the character/bytes and do a wrong replacement.

Your expected string `二建集 - \u4E8C\u5EFA\u96C6` is returned as `二���集 - \u4E8C\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u96C6`. Whereas if the encoding for `建 - \u5EFA` would be broken it should be replaced only by a single replacement character as `二�集 - \u4E8C\uFFFD\u96C6`.

Is there any code involved which assumes 8 bit characters and maybe tries to replace a `^ - 0x5E` by another character?

All possible replacements which would lead into the replacement character can be discovered with following snippet.

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0xFA}; // the bytes for 建
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    b[0] = (byte) i;
    char c = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE).charAt(0);
    if (c == 0xFFFD) { // check if the encoding lead to the replacement character
        System.out.print((char) i);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
}
```

output

```
Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
```

This could explain why the character `建` gets garbled. But would not give an answer to the question from where the other two replacement characters � are.

But maybe this already helps to get closer to the origin of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis . Let me try this out